# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PicController#favorite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am getting an error in my Rails app when I try to favourite a picture from a list of tweets getting pulled in using Twitter API.

Here's the `pic_controller.rb`

```
class PicController < ApplicationController
    def favorite
        if current_user.present?
          pic = Pic.find(params[:url])
          FavPic.create pic: pic, user: current_user
          # user and pic automaically have this `FavPic` assigned
        end
    end
end
```

and here's the `user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first || create_from_omniauth(auth)
    user.oauth_token = auth["credentials"]["token"]
    user.oauth_secret = auth["credentials"]["secret"]
    user.save!
    user
  end

  def self.create_from_omniauth(auth)
    create! do |user|
      user.provider = auth["provider"]
      user.uid = auth["uid"]
      user.name = auth["info"]["nickname"]
    end
  end

  def twitter
    if provider == "twitter"
      @twitter ||= Twitter::Client.new(oauth_token: oauth_token, oauth_token_secret: oauth_secret)
    end
  end

  has_many :fav_pics
  has_many :pics_favorited,
    class_name: 'Pic',
    through: :fav_pics

end

class FavPic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :pic
end

class Pic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :fav_pics
  has_many :fav_users,
    class_name: 'User',
    through: :fav_pics
end
```

Not sure where I am going wrong or how to trouble shoot but this is the error I'm getting. `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "pics" does not exist LINE 5: WHERE a.attrelid = '"pics"'::regclass ^ : SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum WHERE a.attrelid = '"pics"'::regclass AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped ORDER BY a.attnum`

Comment: Have you run `rake db:migrate`? assuming you have a migration to create the `pics` table.

Comment: @diego.greyrobot how do i create a migration like that? I guess that's what I'm missing because I ran `rake db:migrate` as suggested on many q's I've looked through

Comment: show you `schema.rb` file

Comment: Did you use `rails g model Pic` to create that model? If not you can generate the migration with `rails g migration create_pics_table` then write a `create_table` statement as shown here: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_table

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create first a migration table for this run "rails g migration create_(name of the table)". Then after execute, run in terminal "rake db:migrate".